# Get User Location with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the the users current location address(city, street etc) on click event.

I have tried html5 geolocation and tried to console the data. on button click i am checking geo location is supported by creating alert box, and its executes succesfully, But its not printing any values in the console.

HTML

```
<div id="navbar"><span> Geolocation API</span></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<button id="location-button">Get User Location</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

My script

```
  <script>
      $('#location-button').click(function(){

        if (navigator.geolocation) {  
         alert("it is supported");
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
              console.log(position);
              $.get( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude +"&sensor=false", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
              })
              var img = new Image();
              img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&zoom=13&size=800x400&sensor=false";
              $('#output').html(img);
            });

        }
        else
        {
            console.log("geo location is not supported")
        }
      });
 </script>
```

I want to get the full address of the users location.

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/h75Lqd4j/), geolocation only works over `https:`), once I change that to `https:`, I get a "no key" error in the static map request.  Note the geocoder request will not work from javascript, use the javacript API, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499663/google-maps-api-key-http-restriction-causes-403-error-in-geocoding-api

Answer (score 0):

You may visit this [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/6rps70q8/1/) that demonstrates your use case.

Kindly note that it is not recommended to use web service in the client side, as web service requests are recommended to be used for server side requests.

As you can see below, what I used is a [Geocoder Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) instead of the Web Service Geocoding

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'location': pos}, function(results, status, infowindow) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
            console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found: '+ results[0].formatted_address);
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.open(map);
      } else {
                console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -4):

you simply can't! Geolocation use triangulation or GPS from the mobile and you'll get get longitude and latitude values or even the IP and you'll get nearest distributor device(haven't right word in english).
Obviously for geolocation the user have to authorize it too.
So if you want address the simpliest is to ask by a form. You can use a map related with longit/latitude matching but it'll be a pain and waste to do because you've to use all maps and places on earth related to use it that way.